# Socketio - flask server and c# client

Tags: c#, python, flask, flask-socketio

Hey I'm trying to create a messaging app using SocketIO. I have a server written in flask and a client written in C#. I'm using `SocketIoClientDotNet`for the client (https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet).

This is my code:

Flask: routes.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "hello"


@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print("CONNECTED")


@socketio.on("message")
def test():
    print("TEST WORKS")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

C# :

```
public static class EnvConnections {

    public static IO.Options CreateOptions() {
        var options = new IO.Options();
        options.Port = 5000;
        options.Hostname = "127.0.0.1";
        options.ForceNew = true;

        return options;
    }




public static void Connect() {
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:5000");
    var socket = IO.Socket(uri, CreateOptions()); //also tried to create the socket only with url IO.Socket("http://127.0.0.1:5000")


    socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () => {
        Console.Write("EVENT_CONNECT");
        socket.Disconnect();
    });

    socket.Connect(); //tried to remove this 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

On both platforms nothing is printed. It looks like a connection is created between them (on flask this line is printed infinitely once the connection is establish : `127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2016 11:23:43] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=635888858234059292-4049&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -`)

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: after I installed `gevent` I started receiving connect events. The problem is that its stuck on it and no other function is called. Looking at the flask console it looks like it uses pulling instead of webSocket (some kind of fullback mechanism) so I tried to change the c# socket option:

```
    IO.Options options  = new IO.Options();
    //options.Transports = ImmutableList.Create<string>(Polling.NAME);
    options.Upgrade = true;
    var socket = IO.Socket("http://127.0.0.1:5000", options);
```

But it keeps printing transport=polling

Edit2:

```
fb0f4c189334468dba90255880b528a4: Sending packet MESSAGE with 0
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2016 17:49:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=635889089536079075-2035&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 355 0.002000
5cea6ce4dd8b47d79e79dd96747c26e4: Sending packet OPEN with {'pingTimeout': 60000, 'sid': '5cea6ce4dd8b47d79e79dd96747c26e4', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000}
5cea6ce4dd8b47d79e79dd96747c26e4: Sending packet MESSAGE with 0
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2016 17:49:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=635889089536109077-2036&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 355 0.003000
f768281808204af995421b4dbb2cda1c: Sending packet OPEN with {'pingTimeout': 60000, 'sid': 'f768281808204af995421b4dbb2cda1c', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000}
CONNECTED
CONNECTED
f768281808204af995421b4dbb2cda1c: Sending packet MESSAGE with 0
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2016 17:49:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=635889089536149079-2037&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 355 0.002000
e4eb16fcd12f41898ba58a309014b85c: Sending packet OPEN with {'pingTimeout': 60000, 'sid': 'e4eb16fcd12f41898ba58a309014b85c', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000}
e4eb16fcd12f41898ba58a309014b85c: Sending packet MESSAGE with 0
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2016 17:49:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=635889089536179081-2038&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 355 0.002000
70f45826d89b42bba3842e41b8ae8b08: Sending packet OPEN with {'pingTimeout': 60000, 'sid': '70f45826d89b42bba3842e41b8ae8b08', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000}
70f45826d89b42bba3842e41b8ae8b08: Sending packet MESSAGE with 0
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2016 17:49:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=635889089536219083-2039&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 355 0.002000
CONNECTED
CONNECTED
```

Comment: To have WebSocket available you have to have gevent or eventlet installed, and the client should support upgrades, so that part appears to be okay. Please add logging to the server, by initializing the server as `socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)`. Then please add a log session to your question.

Comment: Edited with logger info

Comment: The client is repeatedly trying to connect with the server. For some reason it keeps sending connection requests. In the short log that you pasted there are 5 different connections, which you can differentiate by looking at the 'sid' values (the long sequence of hex characters). I recommend that you test the same server with the official Javascript client and compare the output of the server log. You may then need to take the two logs to the developer of the C# client.

Comment: Hi, you ever got that combination working? Hitting the same problem here...

Comment: No.. I opened an issue on git back then and they closed it at some point (I haven't tried it again and I don't know if it got fixed). Eventually I just used tcp socket.

Comment: Thanks. Just found something: If I hack SocketIOClientDotNet to not try the polling transport first and then upgrade to websockets, it works. So there must be something that prevents the upgrading. On the server side logs I see that the upgrade is offered, but so far I couldn't figure out why the client doesn't go ahead and perform the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

To turn my comment into a proper answer:

The problem appears to be that the upgrading mechanism from long-polling to WebSockets does not work between these particular socket.io implementations. By configuring the client to directly use WebSockets, I got it to work. Here an example:

```cs
var socket = IO.Socket("http://127.0.0.1:5000/data", new IO.Options
{
    // The protocol upgrading does not properly work between Flask-SocketIO and SocketIOClientDotNet
    Transports = ImmutableList<string>.Empty.Add(WebSocket.NAME)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the encoding sent back by the server. Flask Socket IO is not returning text/plain which is what is meant to return when a base64 parameter is included in the request (b64=1). Instead it returns an octet-stream.
The C# library adds b64=1 to the request automatically and changing the ForceBase64 property doesn't change that unfortunately. 
Currently the only way I have found to fix this is to adjust the source for EngineIoClientDotNet, editing Polling.cs and removing query.Add("b64","1").
This may have untoward effects if the library doesn't support binary but so far it is now connecting successfully.